# python mock.mock_calls does not follow calls made inside @timeout decorated function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm unit-testing a function with mock, and trying to test if a call to mock object was made. In the code below the `requests.post` object is mocked, and I track the `requests.post.mock_calls` list.

In the following code the

Code construct:

```
import timeout_decorator

def block_funds(trader_id, amounts):

    @timeout_decorator.timeout(3, use_signals=False)
    def _block_funds(block_url, amounts):

        # requests.post.mock_calls empty here
        result = requests.post(url=block_url, data=amounts)
        # requests.post.mock_calls here has correct call recorded

        return result.status_code

    block_url = 'http:/someurl/somepath/{trader_id}'.format(trader_id=trader_id)

    try:

        # requests.post.mock_calls empty here
        code = _block_funds(block_url, amounts)
        # requests.post.mock_calls empty again here

    except timeout_decorator.TimeoutError as ex:
        logger.error('request failed')
        code = 500

    return code
```

After the call to `code = _block_funds(block_url, amounts)` I expect the mock object to keep record of all calls to it, but the `mock_calls` list gets emptied as soon as the execution exits the internal timeout wrapped function `_block_funds()`. Mock object is certainly the same, I'm following the mock IDs to ensure object has not changed.

What I'm doing wrong and how to make the mock not forget it's calls?

Comment: The mock object you are using for comparison in your test and the one you are testing values on in the function are probably not the same object. Include your test function in your question.

Comment: Actually I've found the cause - it's the `@timeout` decorator. No, the object is the same, I'm following mock object ID, but I've found out that as soon as I comment out the timeout decorator - the call appears and test passes. I will now have to figure out how to workaround that for the test.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue, it's in the timeout decorator, and specifically - in the `use_signals=False` part of it. As per [timeout decorator documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator), to use timeouts correctly in my scenario (multithreaded web application) you need to not use signals and rely on multiprocessing instead, and in this case I see this unexpected mock that causes the problem. If I remove `use_signals=False` or remove decorator completely - it works fine.

My solution for now will be to mock the decorator itself also and avoid the issue.

**Correction**

Directly mocking the decorator turned out to be impractical. Instead I've wrapped it around and mocked the wrap:

```
def timeout_post(**kwargs):
    @timeout_decorator.timeout(3, use_signals=False)
    def _post(**kwargs):
        return requests.post(**kwargs)

    return _post(**kwargs)
```